# Vuejs3 import into composable

Tags: vuejs3, papaparse

I want to use the functionally of the [vue-papa-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-papa-parse/v/3.0.0#default-import-vue-2) in a composable file.  I have tested and found vue-papa-parse to work as described when I import it into a vue component.  But I can't figure out how to import it into my JavaScript composable function.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VuePapaParse from 'vue-papa-parse'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(VuePapaParse)
app.mount('#app')
```

usePapaParse.js

```
import VuePapaParse from 'vue-papa-parse'
        
export default function usePapaParse(){
    function csvToJson(){
        this.$papa.parse('name,address,city,state,zip') // error, can't read parse of undefined
        
        console.log(this.$papa.data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you are not in the scope of a `.vue` file and thus do not have injected defaults.

I suspect this library exposes some export that you can use directly.

try to call some function directly on the imported object

```
import VuePapaParse from 'vue-papa-parse'

//maybe VuePapaParse.parse
VuePapaParse.someFunc
```

second approach

```
import * as papa from 'vue-papa-parse'

//check what intellisense shows here
papa.<something>
```

Comment: I have managed to get it working in component.vue but not in index.js.  I've been tryign to run all my common functions out of index.js but this has been a super big problem, scope seems to be it's own.  Even intellisense is broken along with debugging in Dev Tools.  I think I'm giving up on trying to have global functions until I learn more about Vue... this was never a problem in AngualrJS.  lol  Thanks for offering a suggestion.